# Number of representations of sums of four squares?

Tags: number-theory

I was told that multinomial expansion can be used to determine how many representations of four squares a number like 53 has?  I have a number theory textbook and have done some googleing neither has turned up anything much on this method. Can any of you shed any light?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem

Comment: yeah I know that method but apparently there is a way to use multinomial expansion to get the answer.